# When should I use Unicode string?

Tags: python, django, unicode

I reflect **when should I use Unicode string** in Python 2.7 and my django applications.

Is it good habit to use convention `u'some string'` for **every string** ?

For example:

```
// models.py
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
class ModelClass(models.Model)
   field_name = models.ForeignKey(SomeModel, related_name=u'some_models')
   # ...

       class Meta:
          ordering = (u'created', u'name',)
```

and

```
// urls.py
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
urlpatterns = patterns(u'',
    url(r'^a/$', views.some_view(), name=u'a'),
    url(r'^b/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.some_view2(), name=u'b'),
)
```

?

Comment: There's probably no correct answer to this, but from a performance POV, using regular strings will be more efficient. So, unless you're actually using characters outside the ASCII range, then I'd stick with regular strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO you should use Unicode wherever you have text. You never know if Jürgen, Søren or Joël are going to present their *œuvre* in the context of your application.

When you have data to be transferred to another process or to a file, you should have them as regular string (Py2) resp. `bytes()` object (Py3). In order to identify the interface between these realms, you must be a little careful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use unicode encoding everywhere in your application internally. However, you may pay attention when it comes to In/Out.

> One problem is the multi-byte nature of encodings; one Unicode
>   character can be represented by several bytes. If you want to read the
>   file in arbitrary-sized chunks (say, 1K or 4K), you need to write
>   error-handling code to catch the case where only part of the bytes
>   encoding a single Unicode character are read at the end of a chunk.
>   One solution would be to read the entire file into memory and then
>   perform the decoding, but that prevents you from working with files
>   that are extremely large; if you need to read a 2Gb file, you need 2Gb
>   of RAM. (More, really, since for at least a moment you’d need to have
>   both the encoded string and its Unicode version in memory.)

Most important tip according to [HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

> The most important tip is:
>
> Software should only work with Unicode strings internally, converting
>   to a particular encoding on output.